# .htaccess being ignored when under SSL / port 443

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have rather basic htaccess document that forwards the request to be handled by a php file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller.php [L]
```

This works fine when browsing normally. However, if I switch to using https it no longer will listen to anything in the htaccess document.

I am just wondering is this a server configuration issue and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that content is loaded from the same directory as for non-ssl version. In some configuration for example default for http is public_html directory and for https private_html directory. .htaccess should work without any problem if content is loaded from the same directory in both cases

Comment: It is all within the same directory. HTTPS works fine with standard files when they physically exist. But doesn't work with a controller.

Comment: In my opinion in this case it's server configuration issue. You should contact your server administrator to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

It was a httpd.conf issue with the AllowOverride being set to None instead of All. With this set to None it wouldn't allow htaccess to work over SSL port

Found from: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=31351

"Open the Apache configuration file located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All inside the DocumentRoot Directory Directive, normally "